# Aerospike Bin Length Less than 14

Tags: java, spring-data, aerospike

I have a very complex business object which contains variable name more than 14 Character.I wonder why aerospike has limit bin name length <14.Is there any way or hack so that I can save this complex business object in Aerospike without reducing length of object name as it would be typical to understand if I reducen the name of every variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is no. Bin name is hard coded to be 14 characters or less.  It is stored along with every record on the SSD, for each bin in the record.  Since, each record is self describing a trade-off has to be made between overhead per record and max bin name size.

Comment: can you explain this `a trade-off has to be made between overhead per record and max bin name size`?

Comment: Well, if the database designers gave you a say fixed up to 64 characters for bin name, for each bin in the record, you would be storing all those character bytes, whether you used them or on. So as a design decision, database designers have to decide is 14 characters good enough -- because this space becomes the associated overhead with the record.

Comment: oh! yes got it. You are right. But 14 still looks an odd number to choose. Was there some specific performance benefit of using this?

Comment: @pgupta, we wouldn't need to occupy N bytes whether your needed them or not. Aerospike 4.2 (when released) will only require the number of bytes in the bin-name itself + 1 byte for the length.

Comment: @swayamraina, I'm not sure about the exact motivation for limiting the size to 14 characters specifically. But the current motivation to limiting the length to a small number of characters is that the bin names are currently required to be written to disk with each record. The size limit is a bit of a safeguard to prevent users from unintentionally overwhelming the storage layer with large bin names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as said by @pgupta, The 14 character limit is hardcoded. If you really want to save, what you can do is create a mapping with actual bin name i.e. a 14 character long id and the business object name at the application level. Maybe create a `Map` or an `Enum`